# Parsing Nested JSON in Haskell with Aeson

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I'm trying to parse JSON from a RESTful API. The returned JSON is highly nested and may/may not include certain fields. Here is an example of some returned data:

```
{
    resultSet : {
        location : [{
                desc : "Tuality Hospital/SE 8th Ave MAX Station",
                locid : 9843,
                dir : "Eastbound",
                lng : -122.978016886765,
                lat : 45.5212880911494
            }
        ],
        arrival : [{
                detour : false,
                status : "estimated",
                locid : 9843,
                block : 9024,
                scheduled : "2014-03-02T16:48:15.000-0800",
                shortSign : "Blue to Gresham",
                dir : 0,
                estimated : "2014-03-02T16:48:15.000-0800",
                route : 100,
                departed : false,
                blockPosition : {
                    at : "2014-03-02T16:16:43.579-0800",
                    feet : 3821,
                    lng : -122.9909514,
                    trip : [{
                            progress : 171494,
                            desc : "Hatfield Government Center",
                            pattern : 140,
                            dir : 1,
                            route : 100,
                            tripNum : "4365647",
                            destDist : 171739
                        }, {
                            progress : 0,
                            desc : "Cleveland Ave",
                            pattern : 10,
                            dir : 0,
                            route : 100,
                            tripNum : "4365248",
                            destDist : 3577
                        }
                    ],
                    lat : 45.5215368,
                    heading : 328
                },
                fullSign : "MAX Blue Line to Gresham",
                piece : "1"
            }, {
                detour : false,
                status : "estimated",
                locid : 9843,
                block : 9003,
                scheduled : "2014-03-02T17:05:45.000-0800",
                shortSign : "Blue to Gresham",
                dir : 0,
                estimated : "2014-03-02T17:05:45.000-0800",
                route : 100,
                departed : false,
                blockPosition : {
                    at : "2014-03-02T16:34:33.787-0800",
                    feet : 3794,
                    lng : -122.9909918,
                    trip : [{
                            progress : 171521,
                            desc : "Hatfield Government Center",
                            pattern : 140,
                            dir : 1,
                            route : 100,
                            tripNum : "4365648",
                            destDist : 171739
                        }, {
                            progress : 0,
                            desc : "Cleveland Ave",
                            pattern : 10,
                            dir : 0,
                            route : 100,
                            tripNum : "4365250",
                            destDist : 3577
                        }
                    ],
                    lat : 45.5216054,
                    heading : 345
                },
                fullSign : "MAX Blue Line to Gresham",
                piece : "1"
            }
        ],
        queryTime : "2014-03-02T16:35:21.039-0800"
    }
}
```

As you can see, the JSON schema starts with a `resultSet` which contains a `location`, `arrival`, and `queryTime`. The `location` in turn, contains a list of locations, `arrival` contains a list of arrivals, and `queryTime` is just a UTC time. Then, an `arrival` can contain a `blockPosition`, which can contain a `trip`, etc. Lots of nesting. Lots of optional fields.

To hold all this, I've created a set of new data types. The data types are nested similarly. For each data type, I have an instance of FromJSON (from the Aeson library).

```
-- Data Type Definitions and FromJSON Instance Definitions ---------------------


data ResultSet
     = ResultSet     { locations    :: LocationList
                      ,arrivals     :: ArrivalList
                      ,queryTime    :: String
                     } deriving Show

instance FromJSON ResultSet where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    ResultSet <$> ((o .: "resultSet") >>= (.: "location"))
              <*> ((o .: "resultSet") >>= (.: "arrival"))
              <*> ((o .: "resultSet") >>= (.: "queryTime"))
  parseJSON _ = mzero

data TripList        = TripList     {triplist     :: [Trip]}     deriving Show

instance FromJSON TripList where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    TripList <$> (o .: "trip")
  parseJSON _ = mzero

data LocationList    = LocationList {locationList :: [Location]} deriving Show

instance FromJSON LocationList where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    LocationList <$> (o .: "location")
  parseJSON _ = mzero

data Location
     = Location      { loc_desc           :: String
                      ,loc_locid          :: Int
                      ,loc_dir            :: String
                      ,loc_lng            :: Double
                      ,loc_lat            :: Double
                     } deriving Show

instance FromJSON Location where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    Location <$> (o .: "desc")
              <*> (o .: "locid")
              <*> (o .: "dir")
              <*> (o .: "lng")
              <*> (o .: "lat")
  parseJSON _ = mzero

data ArrivalList     = ArrivalList  {arrivalList  :: [Arrival]}  deriving Show

instance FromJSON ArrivalList where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    ArrivalList <$>  (o .: "arrival")
  parseJSON _ = mzero

data Arrival
     = Arrival       { arr_detour         :: Bool
                      ,arr_status         :: String
                      ,arr_locid          :: Int
                      ,arr_block          :: Int
                      ,arr_scheduled      :: String
                      ,arr_shortSign      :: String
                      ,arr_dir            :: Int
                      ,estimated      :: Maybe String
                      ,route          :: Int
                      ,departed       :: Bool
                      ,blockPosition  :: Maybe BlockPosition
                      ,fullSign       :: String
                      ,piece          :: String
                     } deriving Show

instance FromJSON Arrival where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    Arrival <$> (o .: "detour")
            <*> (o .: "status")
            <*> (o .: "locid")
            <*> (o .: "block")
            <*> (o .: "scheduled")
            <*> (o .: "shortSign")
            <*> (o .: "dir")
            <*> (o .:? "estimated")
            <*> (o .: "route")
            <*> (o .: "departed")
            <*> (o .:? "blockPosition")
            <*> (o .: "fullSign")
            <*> (o .: "piece")
  parseJSON _ = mzero

data BlockPosition  
     = BlockPosition { bp_at                 :: String
                      ,bp_feet               :: Int
                      ,bp_lng                :: Double
                      ,bp_trip               :: Trip
                      ,bp_lat                :: Double
                      ,bp_heading            :: Int 
                      } deriving Show

instance FromJSON BlockPosition where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    BlockPosition <$> (o .: "at")
              <*> (o .: "feet")
              <*> (o .: "lng")
              <*> (o .: "trip")
              <*> (o .: "lat")
              <*> (o .: "heading")
  parseJSON _ = mzero

data Trip           
     = Trip          { trip_progress      :: Int
                      ,trip_desc          :: String
                      ,trip_pattern       :: Int
                      ,trip_dir           :: Int
                      ,trip_route         :: Int
                      ,trip_tripNum       :: Int
                      ,trip_destDist      :: Int
                     } deriving Show

instance FromJSON Trip where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    Trip <$> (o .: "progress")
         <*> (o .: "desc")
         <*> (o .: "pattern")
         <*> (o .: "dir")
         <*> (o .: "route")
         <*> (o .: "tripNum")
         <*> (o .: "destDist")
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

Now, the problem: Retrieving the data is easy.  I can show the raw JSON by

```
json <- getJSON stopID
putStrLn (show (decode json :: (Maybe Value)))
```

But when I try to get the ResultSet data, it fails with `Nothing`.

```
putStrLn (show (decode json :: Maybe ResultSet))
```

However, if I remove the nested data and simply try to get the `queryString` field (by removing the fields from the data type and instance of FromJSON, it succeeds and returns the queryString field.

```
data ResultSet
     = ResultSet     { 
                      queryTime    :: String
                     } deriving Show

instance FromJSON ResultSet where
  parseJSON (Object o)
   = ResultSet <$> ((o .: "resultSet") >>= (.: "queryTime"))
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this the easiest method of parsing JSON in Haskell? I'm a total noob at this (a student), so please be gentle.

Comment: The problem is probably either that your parser has some error or that the input doesn't look like you think it does. You should try to use the eitherDecode function instead of decode to get an error message and paste it here.

Comment: Style point: in the parseJSON for ResultSet you should extract the ResultSet once and then interrogate it. You are doing three seperate lookups for the same value.

Comment: @Reite: Using eitherDecode does indeed reveal an mzero error. This tells me that my FromJSON Instance is not right. It looks like my pattern matching is falling through to the `parseJSON _ = mzero` pattern.  But why? I have examined the incoming JSON. The location field is there.

Comment: I'm intrigued by @PaulJohnson's comment. Am I duplicating the JSON extraction? Is this a clue to why this is failing?

If my pattern matching is failing, that means that I don't have an `Object o` coming into my function. I do if I only have a queryTime, but when I add the location, it fails. Am I using the right design pattern for parsing nested JSON?

Comment: A parsed JSON object is represented as a hash table mapping key names to field values. The (.:) operator is a table lookup. But this shouldn't make any difference to your result.

Answer (score 13):

I solved my problem. I was trying to create data types for my lists of JSON objects returned.  For example, for location data, which is returned as a list of locations:

```
resultSet : {
  location : [{
      desc : "Tuality Hospital/SE 8th Ave MAX Station",
      locid : 9843,
      dir : "Eastbound",
      lng : -122.978016886765,
      lat : 45.5212880911494
    }
  ],
```

I was setting up an `Arrivals` data type containing a list of `[Arrival]`:

```
data ArrivalList     = ArrivalList  {arrivalList  :: [Arrival]}  deriving Show
```

Then, when I tried to parse the JSON, I was trying to stuff an ArrivalList into my ResultSet, which is later used to parse the JSON data inside it. But since ArrivalList is not a JSON object, it was failing.

The fix is to NOT use custom data types for the lists. Instead, assign a list to a JSON !Array object, which can later be parsed into its own objects and sub-objects.

```
 data ResultSet
      = ResultSet     {
                        locations    :: !Array
                       ,arrivals     :: !Array
                       ,queryTime    :: String
                      } deriving Show
```

Putting it all together:

```
data ResultSet
    = ResultSet     {
                      locations    :: !Array
                      ,arrivals     :: !Array
                      ,queryTime    :: String
                    } deriving Show

instance FromJSON ResultSet where
  parseJSON (Object o) = ResultSet <$>
                        ((o .: "resultSet") >>= (.: "location"))
                    <*> ((o .: "resultSet") >>= (.: "arrival"))
                    <*> ((o .: "resultSet") >>= (.: "queryTime"))
  parseJSON _ = mzero

data Location
    = Location      { loc_desc           :: String
                      ,loc_locid          :: Int
                      ,loc_dir            :: String
                      ,loc_lng            :: Double
                      ,loc_lat            :: Double
                    } deriving Show

instance FromJSON Location where
  parseJSON (Object o) =
    Location <$> (o .: "desc")
              <*> (o .: "locid")
              <*> (o .: "dir")
              <*> (o .: "lng")
              <*> (o .: "lat")
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried `!Array`. It won't parse further.

I found what [this blog](http://blog.gnclmorais.com/aeson-and-nested-json) says.

"Aeson can even parse a nested JSON if state correctly."

We just need to use [] in field definition like `photo :: [Photo]`, making the parser keep parsing an array.